# Is there a possibility to remove rows and columns XLSX

Tags: ruby, axlsx

I want to create pretty looking sheet, for this purpose I need only 8 columns and 26 rows, so I would like to remove redundant rows and columns. Is this possible using `axlsx` gem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) there is no way to limit the excel rows and columns. There is an open issue in [axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/issues/490) gem.

If you want to limit the rows and columns you can use [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) file.